# Changing state of a web application at runtime

Tags: java, web-services

I have created a web service simulator using cxf in the form of a standalone web application.

This simulator can behave in different modes like 'no action',error , timeout , action required based on the property file configuration.

For eg. timeout.mode=1

I want to give the capability to the user to modify the mode of the simulator at runtime from front end without restarting the app.

This needs modifying property file at the physical location at runtime.

Is it reliable to try to modify the property file in exploded war at runtime or please suggest some better way of achieving this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy a Servlet that changes an attribute on the application ServletContext that contains the mode.

The value set by the servlet on the ServletContext attribute, could be read from a parameter.

This way, you invoke the Servlet and send the mode you want to set, using a parameter on the servlet's url query string. This allows you to change the mode value dinamically without restarting the app. Better than that, you can do it remotely, without accessing to the server console.

You could also load the ServletContext attribute using a Listener.

If you don't want to use a Servlet for some reason, you could develop another web service to do the same job.

Comment: Will changing the server context attribute be visible to other web applications accessing this simulator web app ??

Comment: No. But you could develop a second Servlet or Web Service that reads and returns that value.

Comment: If you're using Spring, you can use Spring's ApplicationContext to store the value, instead of the ServletContext.